# Response code and error message from service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest, wcf

I am having this statement where I get the return values of the properties of object alone `DoctorDetails` being filled.

```
var details= _clientService.GetAsync<DoctorDetails>(getDetails).Result;
```

I am wondering if there is a way to find the response code and also the error message if any. Because, when I hit the service with improper input, it does show an error message and response code as 400 in swagger. However, when I hit the endpoint, it is not the case, it just show a line of XML with just the namespace(So I am assuming the service is not returning anything apart from this `DoctorDetails`). Is that correct?

Comment: `_clientService` is abstracting that detail away. We have no way of knowing what that custom class is or what it does or if you have control of the implementation, so we can't give any definitive advice. Also don't do `.Result` it can deadlock.

Comment: @Crowcoder: Thank you, I vaguely understood what you said as I am newbie lol. So again, can I know the response code and error message or not? You working for Microsoft/MSDN? Your answer makes me feel so lol. Good one

Comment: It looks to me like you would only have access to response code inside of `GetAsync`, or inside of something it calls. I'm saying we cannot know based on that one line of code. My strong suspicion is no, you cannot access that data.

Comment: @Crowcoder: Thank you so much, at least I can tell my superiors. Cheers